# Matlab function argument passing

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

Does specifying the input parameters in a function call in terms of output of other functions affect performance? 
Would the peak memory usage be affected?
Would it be better if I use temporary variables and clear them after each intermediate step has been calculated?

For ex:

```
g=imfill(imclearborder(imdilate(Inp_img,strel('square',5))),'holes');
```

or

```
temp1=imdilate(Inp_img,strel('square',5));
temp1=imclearborder(temp1);
g=imfill(temp1,'holes');
clear temp1
```

Which would be better in terms of peak memory usage and speed?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, using function calls just uses hidden temporary variables which are cleared. Someone might have some more in depth knowledge. You could try both ways and use the `profiler` to find out, and let us know if there are any differences!

Comment: I expect both solutions to be equally memory intensive unless the JIT discriminates among the two solutions. Also, if you're planning to reuse `temp1`, then the second approach should be preferred (again unless the JIT 'caches' intermediate results for further calculations). If you're on windows, try both solutions with the task manager open and check memory use.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends.

From the top of my head (meaning, I could be wrong):

MATLAB uses a lazy copy-on-write scheme for variable assignment. That means,

```
a = rand(5);
b = a;
```

will *not* create an explicit copy of `a`. In essence, `b` is just a reference. However, when you issue

```
b(2) = 4;
```

the full contents of `a` will be copied into a new variable, the location where `b` points to is changed to that new copy, and the new contents (4) is written.

The same goes for passing arguments. If you issue

```
c = myFcn(a, b);
```

and `myFcn` only *reads* data from `a` and `b`, these variables are never copied explicitly to the function's workspace. But, if it *writes* (or otherwise makes changes) to `a` or `b`, their contents will be copied.

So, in your particular case, I think the peak memory for

```
r = myFcn( [some computation] )
```

will be equal to *or less than*

```
T = [some computation];
r = myFcn( T );
clear T;
```

If `myFcn` makes no changes to `T`, there will be no difference at all (save for more hassle on your part, and the risk of forgetting the `clear`).

However, if `myFcn` *changes* `T`, a deep copy will be made, so for a moment `T` will be in memory twice.

The best way to find out is to profile with memory in mind:

```
profile -memory
```

Comment: Matlab will not assign the results of intermediate computations like `[some computation]` to `ans`. The `ans` variable only gets updated if an entire statement, not just some expression in a statement, returns a value but it is not explicitly assigned to a variable. Basically, if it wouldn't get printed out if you omitted the semicolon, it won't update `ans`.

Comment: @AndrewJanke: Thanks, I was a bit fuzzy on the details. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the question you asked as far as the 'letter of the law' is concerned 'per se', (and apologies if I'm making assumptions) but as far as the 'spirit of the law' is concerned, I understand the implied question to be "does writing things as 'ugly' one-liners ever confer any significant optimisation benefits", to which the answer is most definitely no. Partly due to matlab's lazy evaluation, as rody pointed out above.

So I would prefer the second version, simply because it is more readable. It will not have any penalty on performance as far as I'm aware.